# Introducing a proper synonym for "hanging organizer"

Tags: synonyms

Do you know any proper word or phrase interchangeable or synonym for the following: **hanging organizer**

> Take metal cans, for instance, and imagine them in any number of uses,
>   functional or purely as an art form. Can your eyes and mind see the
>   potential metal case, bird feeder or other object in the simple cast
>   off items? What about boxes or clothing? What might be done with
>   these? Boxes can usually serve as new storage containers, and almost
>   always serve as very imaginative forts for the kids, not to mention
>   makeshift pet houses during colder weather. And clothing? Imagine
>   taking old clothing and turning them into vests, hats, **hanging
>   organizers**, or rag rugs. The only limit to using these items in
>   other ways is one's individual creativity and daringness to try.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "hanging organizer"? Perhaps an image?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, I have provided the text to decide it more clear.

Comment: So, do you know what a hanging organizer is or is that what you're trying to find out? Your initial question makes it sound like you know what they are but your text doesn't actually describe what a hanging organizer is.

Comment: By that, I mean if you have any interchangeable or synonym for it.

Comment: There isn't a synonym that's more clear, compact, or effective than "hanging organizer" at least for AmE.  If the target audience is the U.S. then anyone should know what this means or easily be able to find out.  These are common items in domestics stores.  "Closet organizers" might work but it's common to have similar items that hang on the wall or back of doors.

Comment: Hanging organizers span a broad spectrum of devices that come in a variety of shapes and sizes. Any synonym would likely exclude some subset of that spectrum... as @ultrasawblade made a good recommendation, it still does exclude some styles as they're not exclusively used in closets. Some are used in offices or in playrooms to organize kids' toys.  The only two requirements is a series of pockets (for organizing) and the fact that they hang.

Comment: The term "hanging organizer" was coined by marketing people looking for a name for the product they were selling, IMO.  In any case, it's quite a recent term.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that **Hanging organizer** is a broad term meaning any type of item that is used for organization and hangs from a wall, door, ceiling, etc.

Some specific types of hanging organizers might be called:

- closet organizer
- shelf/shelves
- hook/hooks
- rack/wall rack/coat rack
- cubbies

But these all mean slightly different things. There is not a single word that is a true synonym by itself.